# Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete

Tags: command-line, 20.04, wine

I'm trying to install a .exe file on Ubuntu 20.04, and whenever I attempt to install it with wine, I enter

```
wine (Somefile).exe
```

and I get

```
00c0:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 00000000 1 00000000 0 stub
00cc:fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"Bonjour Service"): stub
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
00cc:fixme:iphlpapi:DeleteIpForwardEntry (pRoute 01E2FD64): stub
00cc:fixme:iphlpapi:CreateIpForwardEntry (pRoute 01E2FD2C): stub
0050:fixme:service:svcctl_EnumServicesStatusExW resume handle not supported
0050:fixme:service:svcctl_EnumServicesStatusExW resume handle not supported
0050:fixme:service:svcctl_EnumServicesStatusExW resume handle not supported
0050:fixme:service:svcctl_EnumServicesStatusExW resume handle not supported
00cc:fixme:advapi:ReportEventA (CAFE4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,00000000,0x0001,0x00000000,01E2FAA8,00000000): stub
00cc:fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (CAFE4242,0x0004,0x0000,0x00000064,00000000,0x0001,0x00000000,004892E8,00000000): stub
00cc:fixme:netapi32:NetGetJoinInformation Semi-stub (null) 01E2FB38 01E2FB40
006c:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
006c:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
006c:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
006c:fixme:nsi:ipv6_forward_enumerate_all not implemented
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
00cc:fixme:winsock:WSAIoctl SIO_UDP_CONNRESET stub
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: File not found.
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
```

I've tried multiple files, and all of them will return  the same response. I recently updated to the latest version of wine, and this has started happening ever since I updated. Can someone please help?

Comment: Me also. Please update, if someone changes here.